# Why doesn't method added to the prototype gives an error of "not defined"?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm not understanding prototypes. From what I understand this code should work. I've created a prototype using Object.create and added a method to the prototype but I keep getting an error. So how do I get this code to work properly? Let me rephrase, how do write code properly?

```
// base function
function person()
{
    this.name;
    this.type;
}

//create instance of function
var a = new person();
a.name = 'ha';
console.log(a.name);

//as opposed to creating instance like above, have new object "b" have the function person as its prototype
var b = Object.create(person);
b.name = 'ho';
console.log(b.name);

//add the method height to the prototype, aka. underlying object "person"
b.prototype.height = function(h) {return h * 2;};

console.log(b.height(5));

//scratch head and ask SO why this doesn't work
/*
Exception: b.height is not a function
@Scratchpad/3:26
*/
```

Comment: As Akinkunle Allen says, instances inherit from their constructor's prototype, not the constructor itself. The reference is stored in the internal `[[Prototype]]` property, available in some browsers as `__proto__` and can be assigned to using ES5s [*Object.create*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5).

Answer (score 1):

```
//as opposed to creating instance like above, have new object "b" have the 
//function person as its constructor, person.prototype as its prototype object
var b = Object.create(person); //this is wrong
var b = Object.create(person.prototype); //this is right. b now has person() as its constructor
```

`Object.create()` method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

```
//this wouldnt work because b is an object, not a constructor. 
//If you want b to inherit the height method, define it on the it's constructor's
//prototype object which is person.prototype 
//(NOTE that you created b from person.prototype)
person.prototype.height = function(h) {return h * 2;};
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //as opposed to creating instance like above, have new object "b" have the function person as its prototype
> var b = Object.create(person);
> ```

Yes, that's exactly what happens: You have the *Function* object as the prototype. And it's not what you want! The [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) does create instances that inherit from the constructor's `.prototype` object. So if you want to instantiate objects manually with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), you will need to write

```
var b = Object.create(person.prototype);
// and you might do `person.apply(b)` to invoke the constructor
```

Btw, your `b.prototype.height = function(h){…}` did work fine for the `a` instance, you could have called `console.log(a.height(5))`.

---

However, as your constructor does not do anything, you might as well omit it completely. Without constructors (and their `.prototype` property), you can do pure prototypical inheritance like this:

```
var person = { // the prototype object for all persons
    height: function(h) {return h * 2;}
};

var a = Object.create(person);
a.name = 'ha';

// adding methods to all persons:
person.logName = function() { console.log(this.name); };
a.logName();
```

In contrast, the typical constructor+.prototype approach would look like this:

```
function Person(name) { // constructors are capitalized
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.height = function(h) {return h * 2;};

var a = new Person('ha');

// adding methods to all Persons:
Person.prototype.logName = function() { console.log(this.name); };
a.logName();
```